# Profiling rendering time on gsp files in Grails 3.x

Tags: grails

I have a grails 3.x app in production. In dev environment it takes a second to show a table with 50 rows. But in production environment it takes 10 seconds. I try to profile times but I can not figure how to print the time between every row.

The database is out of question. All queries take a little amount of time. The problem is in rendering the page.

I want to take the time it takes to render the complete page and between rows...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I try to profile times but I can not figure how to print the time
> between every row.

Printing the time between rows would be trivial if you have a custom GSP tag generating the rows.  In the tag you can do anything that is valid Groovy, including logging times.